# Is there a way to clear edittext before bluetooth barcode scanner input

Tags: java, android

I have an `Edittext` and I want to clear it before receiving the input from the next scan by barcode scanner. The problem is that every time I scan a barcode, the input is added to the result of previous scan like this:

id=3id=12id=34

I tried `beforeTextChanged` event and it doesn't work for me!

Comment: What code is responsible for adding the scanner data to the edittext?

Comment: There is a bluetooth scanner that show the scan result inside an EditText. There isn't any code for that. You can see the scan result in any EditText such as sms input box!

Comment: Of course there is code for that. The code that is interacting with the scanner does not just randomly write data to a random edittext. That needs to be specified somewhere, which is in the code. This code is responsible for appending the data instead of clearing the edittext first.

Comment: You can study about that. You will find useful information on internet about what I am saying. @f1sh

Comment: I can add that it's a handheld scanner, not camera scanner.

Comment: You are the person having the question, why do you suggest that I study about this?

Answer (score 0):

> This simple code can clear the editext , Have you tried it ?

```
editText.getText().clear();
```

Comment: The problem is that where I should add this piece of code. I want to clear it right before the next scan. I put it inside beforeTextchanged event but it doesn't work well.

Comment: post your Activity code, so I can analyze the code